# AWS API Gateway insert a request header parameter in the response

Tags: amazon-web-services, gateway

[image]

I have a http proxy in AWS integrating a 3-party system and in my request I have a correlation id that I want to append to the response in order to trace transactions.

How do I append my request header to the response header?

Tips and or examples on how to do this.